# How can I combine or simplify multiple statements

Tags: php, post, submit, file-put-contents

I have repetitive statements and need help to simplify or combine statements They all have similar values and range from jan - dec and the item (sales change to different category in this example sales change to ncvat) changes for 32 different categories and each group has a different submit value

```
if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){
    $xml->sales->jan = $_POST['jan'];
    file_put_contents("2020/data.xml", $xml->asXML());
}

...................................
...................................

if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){
    $xml->sales->dec = $_POST['dec'];
    file_put_contents("2020/data.xml", $xml->asXML());
}
```

then I have

```
if(isset($_POST['submit2'])){
        $xml->ncvat->jan = $_POST['jan'];
        file_put_contents("2020/data.xml", $xml->asXML());
    }
    
    ...................................
    ...................................
    
    if(isset($_POST['submit2'])){
        $xml->ncvat->dec = $_POST['dec'];
        file_put_contents("2020/data.xml", $xml->asXML());
    }
```

And so it carries on for 32 different form submit action

Comment: Is it possible to set a hidden input on each form with a value of `sales` or `ncvat` or have all submit buttons have the same name `submit` but have one of those as value?  Would make it much easier.

Comment: Also, you're overwriting `data.xml` each time and it will only contain `dec` data.  Or do you have different files for each month and type or what?

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 2):

Usually when you have a lot of repetitive tasks, a loop is your best option. In this case, I think 2 loops will solve your problem.

```
//list of "categories". This also dictates how many outer-loops there will be. 
//Duplicates categories are allowed if needed.
$types = [
    'sales',
    'ncvat',
    //...etc
];

//list of months
$months = ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun', 'jul', 'aug', 'sep', 'oct', 'nov', 'dec'];

//loop each `$types`, and use `$key + 1` as an indicator for which "submit value" you are processing
foreach($types as $key => $type)
    
    //to start $sub at `1` instead of `0`
    $submit_value = $key + 1; 

    //check if submit value exists for current loop (e.g $_POST['submit1'])
    if(isset($_POST["submit{$submit_value}"])) {

        //loop each month
        foreach($months as $month) {

            //update xml for current month in current submission loop
            $xml->{$type}->{$month} = $_POST[$month];
        }
    }
}

//submit all changes at once instead of overwriting on each inner-loop.
file_put_contents("2020/data.xml", $xml->asXML());
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like that :

```
$months = [
   'jan',
   'dec',
   ...
];
$numberOfIterations = 32;

for ($i = 1 ; $i <= $numberOfIterations ; $i++) {
   if (isset($_POST["submit{$i}"])) {
      foreach ($months as $month) {
         $xml->ncvat->$month = $_POST[$month];
         file_put_contents("2020/data.xml", $xml->asXML(), FILE_APPEND);
      }
   }
}
```

You can change "ncvat" by, for example, setting up an "hidden" field in your form. Like :

```
<input type="hidden" name="type" value="ncvat">
```

and then :

```
$months = [
   'jan',
   'dec',
   ...
];
$numberOfIterations = 32;

for ($i = 1 ; $i <= $numberOfIterations ; $i++) {
   if (isset($_POST["submit{$i}"])) {
      $type = $_POST['type'];
      foreach ($months as $month) {
         $xml->$type->$month = $_POST[$month];
         file_put_contents("2020/data.xml", $xml->asXML(), FILE_APPEND);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: "the item (sales change to different category in this example sales change to ncvat)"

Comment: Except it could be `ncvat` or `sales` or 30 others.

Comment: Note that someone on the client side could easily change the `type` input field to anything they want, you'd probably want to verify this on the server side anyways with a list of possible values.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton You are right, switch cases would be better so instead of $type = $_POST['type']

Comment: This will overwrite the file `2020/data.xml` in each iteration, which will make every iteration except the last pointless. If you want to append to it, add the `FILE_APPEND` flag

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Appending it would be bad, because each internal loop is supposed to have a different `$type` I think. If you appended it, it would have tons of duplicate data

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton - Sure, we don't have enough info about how they actually want the file, but this will still overwrite the data on every iteration, only leaving the data from the last iteration in the file.

Comment: The way the OP want to manage the file isn't really clear too.

Comment: @ThéoBenoit - True, but overwriting the same file over and over is pointless regardless how they want the end result :-)

Comment: Sorry was away, just read through all suggestions but I missed one vital point mentioning. My form value is pre populated by the data in xml file with following code - value="<?php echo $xml->sales->jan  ?> with submit name="submit1" and value="<?php echo $xml->ncvat->jan  ?> with submit name="submit2" ...... etc so submit1 will always be 'sales' and submit2 will always be 'ncvat' all months will be submit by one button If you change feb the new feb value will be over ride and all the echo values of all other months will be over written by same value. Hope this make sense

Answer (score 0):

If you can pass `sales`, `ncvat` etc. as `type` via a hidden input or the value of the submit buttons with the same name then it is much easier:

```
$months = ['jan', 'feb'];     //etc...
$types  = ['sales', 'ncvat']; //etc...

foreach($months as $month) {
    if(!empty($_POST['type']) && !empty($_POST[$month]) && in_array($_POST['type'], $types)) {
        $xml->{$_POST['type']}->{$month} = $_POST[$month];
        file_put_contents("2020/data.xml", $xml->asXML()); //maybe this goes after the loop?
    }
}
```

If you can't pass the `type` in the form then you can do this to get the submit:

```
$types  = ['submit1' => 'sales', 'submit2' => 'ncvat']; //etc...
$type = reset(array_intersect_key($types, $_POST));
```

However, since you only show `2020/data.xml` and don't specify `FILE_APPEND`, if that is the only file it will be overwritten each time through the loop and you will only have `dec` data.  Maybe you have separate files? Or build the XML and write it only once?

Comment: I just look at my structure of my form. I have the xml file values echoed in my input field - <?php echo $xml->sales->jan  ?> with submit1 (sales = always submit1) and <?php echo $xml->ncvat->jan  ?> with submit2 (ncvat=always submit 2. So all values are pre populated from xml file via echo statement. So If I change one month value that months value will be overwritten with new value and rest of month value will be overwritten with same echo value Hope this will simplify my code

Comment: Added an alternative if you can't change the form (which would be best).